# Как построить график из фрейма данных по времени?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, визуализация

Есть фрейм данных. Как правильно построить график, если нужно чтобы в пределах одной картинки были наложеные графики из `df['2']` с условием:
наложить друг на друга графики каждого дня с `110000` до `140000` `(df['Time'])`?

[Файл](http://file.sampo.ru/qs8fnt/)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('201201.csv')
```

Данные:

```
Date        Time    1       2
20200103    100100  154670  155990
20200103    100200  155940  156090
20200103    100300  156080  156350
20200103    100400  156340  156400
20200103    100500  156400  156610
20200103    100600  156500  156600
20200103    100700  156510  156550
20200103    100800  156540  156580
20200103    100900  156560  156590
```

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Если это не учебное задание, то уточните пожалуйста с чем именно у вас возникли трудности и приведите в вопросе собственную попытку решения

Comment: А как должен выглядеть график для промежутков времени, не попадающих в `с 110000 до 140000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,7))

for dt in df["Date"].unique():
    d = df.query("Date == @dt and 110000 <= Time <= 140000").copy()
    d = d.set_index(pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01 " + d["Time"].astype(str)))
    d["2"].plot(ax=ax)

# plt.legend()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS также советую прочесть [раздел документации о визуализации в Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html)